# Javascript select, get value from name

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm building dynamic drop downs for an order form for additional options. When selected these options increase the value for a dynamic amount. The drop downs are organized as such:

```
<option value=" . $name . ">" . $name . "</option>
```

This is via php and then I just echo it. What I don't know how to do is currently my javascript is set to determine how much to increment the value by the option value, which leaves me looking at numbers in the database and not really knowing what they ordered. So what I thought to do is instead have the php echo something like: `<option value="Test"> Test - $10 </option>` where I could use javascript to cut out the `10` and add it to the total. This is for multiple dropdowns, currently my javascript is:

```
function getDDValue(elementID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var value;
    // if the element exists
    if (element) {
        value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    } else {
        value = 0;
    }
    console.log(value);
    return parseFloat(value);
}

function getBase() {
    var value = 0;
    var element = document.getElementById('base_cost');
    value = element.value;
    return parseFloat(value);
}

function getTotal() {
    var optA = getDDValue("optA");
    var quantity = getDDValue("quantity");
    var optB = getDDValue("optB");
    var optC = getDDValue("optC");
    var base_cost = getBase("base_cost")
    var totalPrice = '0';
    totalPrice = parseFloat((+base_cost + +optA + +optB + +optC) * +quantity);
    console.log(totalPrice);
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "<?php echo $name; ?> $" + totalPrice;
}
getTotal();
```

I'd post what I've tried but I'm not sure where to even start, and as sure as I am that this has been done before I must be asking google and SO the wrong questions in my searches so I haven't found any resources on this. Any help is greatly appreciated on the best way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just put it in the value? I don't know what you mean by "which leaves me looking at numbers in the database and not really knowing what they ordered".

Comment: Because there are going to be 3 dynamic selects which could be relevant to any option, in example size, color, shape, etc. If i just see 15 I have no idea if they are getting a bigger size, a different color, etc. i need to pass the value to mysql as a string in exmaple: `4oz` but that doesnt allow javascript to just update the value (i cant add 4oz to $100).

Comment: That's what arrays are for. Do `<option value="size[10]">Test - 10</option>` and then in PHP this will be in `$_REQUEST['size'][10]`.

Comment: Ill look into this, give me a few minutes. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using  field correctly, the best way to use a `<select>` input is:

```html
    <select name="Test" id="Test" onChange="getTotal(); or any function">
     <option value="10">Test - 10</option>
    </select>
```

**For your current need:**

If you're using JQuery, you can split the Text with "-", and filter second part like `$(secondPart).replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");` to get only a valid number.

Comment: I know how to use an input, what I need help with is to have the value be text so I know what they are ordering, but use javascript to cut the 10 between the option tags out and add it to the total on the user side.

Comment: I put another example for your current need

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom attribute.

```
<option value="Test" data-price="10">Test - $10</option>
```

Get the price in JavaScript like this:

```
parseFloat(element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price"));
```

It looks like you are also using `getDDValue()` to read the selected quantity.  Make sure you leave `getDDValue()` alone so you don't break quantity, and create a new function for getting the option price.

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/BDGWR/1](http://jsfiddle.net/BDGWR/1/)

BTW, using jQuery can really reduce the amount of code you have to write, and is especially helpful when an [unobtrusive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is required, as is the case for you.

jQuery Demo: [jsfiddle.net/BDGWR/2](http://jsfiddle.net/BDGWR/2/)

Comment: This looks about right, let me try it out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be logical but the result it's giving me is NaN though in the html it is showing it as a number. There aren't any issues showing in console either. Any ideas? I'm working on debugging it now.

Comment: I think what is going on is it is literally putting data-price as the value rather than getting the value of data-price

Comment: Hmm. There must be an error in how I'm handling it in my code, I added it to the if condition in the getDDvalue function:   `if(element){
        value = parseFloat(element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }else{
        value = 0;
    }`

Sorry, copied a change I made, here is the one before that.

Comment: @user3070011 - What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @user3070011 - It's probably this line: `getDDValue("quantity")`.  I assume the quantity selector is different from the options selectors in that you want the actual value, and not the price.  Rename `getDDValue()` to something like `getOptionPrice()` and then restore your original `getDDValue()` function.  Use `getDDValue()` for quantity, and `getOptionPrice()` for the other drop down lists.

Comment: Sorry for being MIA, ill try that out asap @gilly